# Vb.Net DataGridView behaves a strange way

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

on a VB.Net form I have a **DataGridView** populated by a **table of a MariaDB DB** with the manual addition of some Combo and Text columns.

In detail:

- fetch data from DB and put it in a **DataTable**
- I use the DataTable as the DataSource of the **`DataGridView`**
- I add manually (I always mean from code) to the DataGridView the columns of type DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and DataGridViewTextBoxColumn with `DataGridView1.Columns.Add(<new column>)`

So far no problems.

So:

- I launch a process from a button on the form that reads the individual rows of the DataGridView with a classic `For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows` loop and, if it is successful, I write OK on a cell (`row.Cells(PosEsito). Value = "OK"`) otherwise an error code.
- with an if I read this cell and if OK, I delete the record on the DB (with a command SQL query) and delete the row of the DataGridView with `DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row)` always inside the loop

It happens that out of 10 lines with an OK result, only 8 or 9 are deleted... never 10.

I'm going crazy to debug this fairly linear code

Do you have any ideas to help me

Thank you

Roberto

Comment: Post your code instead of describing it

Comment: Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn what's required of a question on this site. I'd suggest starting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but don't limit yourself to that.

Answer (score 2):

I see this:

> button on the form that reads the individual rows of the DataGridView with a classic For Each ...

And this:

> delete the row of the DataGridView with DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row) always inside the loop

Those two things together are bad. **You should not modify a collection of any type while you are still iterating the collection with `For Each`.**

Instead, you can save which rows to remove in a separate list to process after, walk the grid (backwards) with a traditional indexed `For` loop, or any of a number of other options that leave the collection unchanged while a `For Each` loop is still active.

Comment: Further, since he is issuing separate DELETE commands to the database, he should be refreshing the data in the DataGridView from the database, IMO. I always do that to ensure the database and UI are in sync after data is inserted, updated, or deleted. So, issue all the delete commands, and then just reload the DGV from the database, and not worry about modifying the existing data bound collection.

Comment: Tanks for solution !!!